# How to remove properties of objects from a array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to remove a key from an object

This function takes an array of user objects and deletes the moto key-value pair on each user object.

I have tried this code:

```
function deleteAllMoto(users) {

   for(var i=0; i<=users.length; i++) {

    delete users[i].password;
    return users[i];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
function deleteAllMoto (arr) {
  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    delete item.moto
  })
  return arr
}
```

From your code you are deleting password not moto, then trying to return each user instead of the whole array after the mutations.

Comment: Yes, It works. One more thing how to count number of objects in the array?

Comment: you can just use `length` e.g. `arr.length`

Answer (score 0):

`deleteAllMoto` function should be

```
function deleteAllMoto(users) {

  for(var i=0; i<=users.length; i++) {
    delete users[i].moto;
  }
  return users;

}
```